# Driver for a ATI Radeon xpress 200m graphics card?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, graphics, ati

I am using ubuntu 10.10. where could i find my graphics card driver for my graphics card ati radeon xpress 200m.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article in Ubuntu documentation web page about open source Radeon driver:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Answer (score 1):

By default you should be using the standard radeon driver. If that isn't good enough, try the [bleeding edge Xorg from the xorg crack pusher team.](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers) Performance with my Radeon x300 shot way up. The compiz window switcher now produces a 3d holograms as the screen flips around workspaces, and with a python module it can enlarge my screenspace without changing the resolution or dpi.

Bear in mind the stern warnings:

> Packages for those who think
>   development versions, experimental and
>   unstable are for old ladies. We want
>   our crack straight from upstream git!
>   Well, straight, we want it built and
>   packaged so we don't need to know what
>   we're doing, except that we will break
>   our X and put our computers on fire.

Also, Xorg windows start shaking if I haven't run `apt-get upgrade` recently.

May need to [add yourself to the video group](https://askubuntu.com/q/22993/8515).

Answer (score 0):

No way for proprietary drivers (those downloaded directly from AMD), since AMD does not provide support for that graphic card. Open source ones shold be already up and running in your system (dmesg | grep -i radeon should provide you with some lines proving that the open source RADEON drivers are working)

Comment: ok but i won't be expecting this one as i have already searched over ati's site for this card's driver. By the way doesn't matter, thanks for response