# Why do I have low FPS unless root?

Tags: root, opengl, framerate

**Problem:**
Normal users aren't using the best graphics driver. I first noticed this playing Osmos from the HumbleBundle2, but I can observe it while running glxgears too. Maximised on a 1280x1024, glxgears averages a choppy 60 frames in 5 seconds, vs a smooth 300 frames every 5 seconds for root.

Here's some glxinfo:

```
jake@daedalus:~$ glxinfo | grep "renderer string"
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
jake@daedalus:~$ sudo glxinfo | grep "renderer string"
[sudo] password for jake: 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI R300 (RV380 5B60) 20090101 x86/MMX+/3DNow!+/SSE2 TCL DRI2
```

I have the same problem even after rebooting (powering down, cycling surge protector). I followed the directions at the [Ubuntu wiki for getting rid of fglrx](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver), but no dice. What else can I do?

**Hardware:**
Radeon x300
AMD Athlon 1.8 GHz
1.5 GB ram

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wonder if adding yourself to the 'video' group (I think) would help?

```
sudo adduser $USERNAME video
```

Can someone confirm the group name? Thx

Comment: Yes, the group is video. Adding myself to the group boosts my regular user's glxgears frame rate 500%. Thanks!

Comment: @djeikyb, shouldn't this be a bug? Did you try and report it at Launchpad? Why are normal users restricted from taking advantage of the hardware capabilty?

Comment: It may be self-inflicted. I would have to test on a clean install on a real machine, not a vm. But yes, could be a bug.

Comment: @djeikyb, I don't think it's self-inflicted since there's this video group to remove all restrictions. And if you reply, please add @Oxwivi - I hate to miss out on replies because I wasn't notified.

Comment: @Oxwivi Oh! Will do, didn't realise that's how comments work. Cool.

Comment: @djeikyb, unless it's my question or answer, I won't be automatically notified - the user must be tagged. Anyway, if you do post a bug, drop a comment here, I'll go and up it. ;)