# function of chown command

Tags: chown, groups

I'm curious to know what the chown command does. In the manual page it says the chown command changes the file owner and group. I know the owner is the one that created the file(unless changed), but what are groups and when do we create a group?

Comment: Search and read up on "linux file permissions and groups". There are several good tutorials.  Most users won't need to create new groups.

Comment: Related: [What do the groups do in “Users and Groups”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26179/what-do-the-groups-do-in-users-and-groups)

Answer (score 0):

This command is used to change the ownership of a file or a folder.
We can change the ownership of a single folder or multiple folders included in it.

Mostly there will be two users.

1. root
2. customuser

NB: 'customuser' is your username. It will be vary with each system. You can check your username with typing `whoami` in terminal.

sometimes you can't copy/move/delete a file from certain folders. Because of the ownership problem. You can check the ownership of a folder by `ll` command (`ll foldername`).

To use `chown`, you should aware of what you gonna do. Else your system got busted. So aware of it.

Here is an example:
I have a folder in home folder named 'test'. And its owner is 'root'. I have many files/folders in 'test' folder. I need to change the ownership of entire 'test' folder and its sub folders to 'customuser'.
I can change the permission by typing:

```
sudo chown -R customuser:customuser /home/customuser/test
```

`-R` means recursive.
first customuser used for owner.
second customuser used for group.

Comment: **WARNING** Many disaster scenarios begin with `sudo chown -R` (or `sudo chmod -R`). Please _do_ _not_ use `sudo chown -R` in an answer to a fairly new user.